# Colorize matched text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, find

I using following code:

```
var search = 'test';
if ($('#sku').find(search) ){
    //alert(search);
    $(document).find(search).css('color','red');


<TABLE>
    <tr>
        <td id='search' > This is searching test !</td>
    </tr>
</TABLE>
```

How can I colorize the word 'test' in my HTML with jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll want to find your matched text and wrap it with a span.

Comment: @dilyan_kn are you searching via ajax and appending the rows?  If so, it may be easier to search the text when you append it, instead of searching the entire document.

Comment: kmb385 Yes I searching and returning result in table, and I want to colorize mached record.

Comment: @dilyan_kn can you post the js that appends the rows?  I think this is where we want to target.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var  testTextBox = $('#search');
        var code =null;
        testTextBox.keypress(function(e)
        {
            code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13){
                var search=$('#search').val();
               document.location.href='index.php?load=search&q='+search;
               $(function() {
    $("#search:contains("+search+")").css('color','red');
});
            }
        });

    });

Comment: After click ENTER I redirect to search page and showing results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
$(function() { 
    var search = "test"; 
    var elm=$("#search");
    elm.html(elm.html().replace(search,"<span style='color:red'>"+search+"</span>"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$(function() {
    var search = "test";
    $("#search:contains("+search+")").css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: This code change color on all <td> I want to colorize match text. Thanks !